# Can I use State<ArrayList<T>> or State<mutableListOf()> for observed by Compose to trigger recomposition when they change?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The following content is from the [article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).

1: I don't understand fully if I can use `State<ArrayList<T>>` or `State<mutableListOf()>` for observed by Compose to trigger recomposition when they change?

2: I'm very strange why `State<List<T>>` and the immutable `listOf()` can be observed by Compose to trigger recomposition when they change but in fact `List<T>` and immutable `listOf()` are immutable, could you give me some sample codes?

> Caution: Using mutable objects such as ArrayList or mutableListOf() as state in Compose will cause your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app.
>
> Mutable objects that are not observable, such as ArrayList or a mutable data class, cannot be observed by Compose to trigger recomposition when they change.
>
> Instead of using
> non-observable mutable objects, we recommend you use an observable
> data holder such as State<List> and the immutable listOf().

**Image**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The core concept is

> Recomposition happens only when an observable state change happens.

For mutable objects, we have options to use `add()`, `remove()` and other methods and modify the object directly.
But the change would not trigger a recomposition as the change is not observable. (The object instance is NOT changed)

Even for mutable objects, we can trigger proper recomposition by assigning them to a new object instance. (The object instance is changed)

Hence using mutable objects is error-prone.

We can also, see a lint error due to this problem.

[image]

On the other hand, an immutable object like `list` can not be modified. They are replaced with a new object instance.
Hence they are observable and proper recomposition happens. (The object instance is changed)

Use this as an example to understand the concept.

```
@Composable
fun ComposeListExample() {
    var mutableList: MutableState<MutableList<String>> = remember {
        mutableStateOf(mutableListOf())
    }
    var mutableList1: MutableState<MutableList<String>> = remember {
        mutableStateOf(mutableListOf())
    }
    var arrayList: MutableState<ArrayList<String>> = remember {
        mutableStateOf(ArrayList())
    }
    var arrayList1: MutableState<ArrayList<String>> = remember {
        mutableStateOf(ArrayList())
    }
    var list: MutableState<List<String>> = remember {
        mutableStateOf(listOf())
    }
    
    Column(
        Modifier.verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        // Uncomment the below 5 methods one by one to understand how they work.
        // Don't uncomment multiple methods and check.
        
        
        // ShowListItems("MutableList", mutableList.value)
        // ShowListItems("Working MutableList", mutableList1.value)
        // ShowListItems("ArrayList", arrayList.value)
        // ShowListItems("Working ArrayList", arrayList1.value)
        // ShowListItems("List", list.value)

        Button(
            onClick = {
                mutableList.value.add("")
                arrayList.value.add("")

                val newMutableList1 = mutableListOf<String>()
                mutableList1.value.forEach {
                    newMutableList1.add(it)
                }
                newMutableList1.add("")
                mutableList1.value = newMutableList1

                val newArrayList1 = arrayListOf<String>()
                arrayList1.value.forEach {
                    newArrayList1.add(it)
                }
                newArrayList1.add("")
                arrayList1.value = newArrayList1

                val newList = mutableListOf<String>()
                list.value.forEach {
                    newList.add(it)
                }
                newList.add("")
                list.value = newList
            },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Add")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ShowListItems(title: String, list: List<String>) {
    Text(title)
    Column {
        repeat(list.size) {
            Text("$title Item Added")
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: Use `mutableStateListOf` if you have a list of items that needs to be modified as well as trigger recomposition properly.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do like this:

```
@Composable
fun ComposeListExample(
    allObjects: List<Object>,
    selectedObjects: List<Object>
) {
    val selectedItems = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<Object>().apply { addAll(selectedObjects) }
    }
    Column {
        allObjects.forEach { item ->
            SomeView(
                title = item.title,
                onSelect = {
                    if (selectedItems.contains(item)) {
                        selectedItems.remove(item)
                    } else {
                        selectedItems.add(item)
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```